# Subclass of UIView with Xib file

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder, subclass

Although I've searched the Board and used google, I didn't get any useful results.
I've trying to make a subclass of UIView loading its view from a xib file.

My approach is the following:
1. Creating a subclass (named mySubclass):

```
@interface mySubclass : UIView {

}

@end
```

2. Creating a view through:
   Add New File...
   User Interface
   View XIB
3. Connecting the Xib and the subclass:
   In IB select the View and set the class to mySubclass.
4. In my viewController I make an instance of my new subclass and add to my view.

   `-(void)viewDidLoad {

   mySubclassIns = [[mySubclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 20)];
   [self.view addSubview:mySubclassIns];

   [super viewDidLoad];
   }`

Result:

Noting shows up in my App :(
If I don't set it up programmatically but rather with IB it doesn't work either.
(Am I setting it up right when choosing a view in IB and set the class to myClass?)

I would be really thankful for your help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

it's given by default in implementation file... you just need ti uncomment it and implement it with your nib name...

Comment: but I only want to add a certain area, not the whole thing. (My example size was not optimal chosen)

Comment: i don't it's related with your question or not but
 [super viewDidLoad];
 should be first line of your 
-(void)viewDidLoad {